# Slack incoming webhook: Request header field Content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: javascript, cors, content-type, slack, fetch-api

I try to post a slack message via the fetch API in a browser:

```
fetch('https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx/xxx/xx', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({text: 'Hi there'})
})
  .then(response => console.log)
  .catch(error => console.error);
};
```

I get the following error message:

```
Fetch API cannot load:
https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxxx/xxxxx. 
Request header field Content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

What to do?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That Slack API endpoint unfortunately appears to be broken in its handling of cross-origin requests from frontend JavaScript code—in that it doesn’t handle the CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request as it should—so the only solution seems to be to omit the `Content-Type` header.

So it looks like you need to remove the following from the `headers` part of your request code:

```
'Content-type': 'application/json'
```

That part triggers your browser to do a [CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests). So, for your browser to allow your frontend JavaScript code to send the `POST` request you’re trying to do, the `https://hooks.slack.com/services` API endpoint must return an `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header that contains `Content-Type` in its value.

But that endpoint doesn’t return that, so the preflight fails and the browser stops right there.

Normally when posting from frontend JavaScript to an API endpoint that expects JSON, adding that `Content-Type: application/json` header to the request is exactly what you need to do and should do. But not in this case—because that  API endpoint doesn’t handle it properly.

Comment: well i am not setting it explicitly so how do i avoid it?

Comment: This worked for me. I just find it strange that from the front-end this doesn't work. Is there any way to handle the preflight?

Answer (score 19):

What worked for me is setting `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

I am using `axios`, and I found this suggestion [in this Github thread](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/475).

It appears that this triggers a "simple request" and therefore avoids triggering CORS preflight: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests

Comment: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` also work with `axios`