# Javascript: Access to fetch at 'https..' from origin 'http...' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors

When I run this command:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: applicatiojson' --data '{"text":"Hello, World!"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXXX/XXX/XXXX
```

Everything posts the way I want. But, in javascript, when I run the post request:

```
fetch('https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXXX/XXX/XXXX', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*"
      },
      text: "Hello, world."
    })
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I thought this was the problem: [Deadly CORS when http://localhost is the origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin)
But then I tried opening my own ngrok and got the same error. I also tried installing the [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) chrome extension to no avail.
Also, as you can see in my code, I set it to allow access for CORS. Lastly, I tried on firefox but still wouldn't work. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Have you tried setting `mode: 'cors'` in the request object? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode

Comment: @MattHolland Just tried it and it didn't work: /oauth.access', {mode: 'cors',method: 'POST', ...

Comment: Check what HTTP response you get for `curl -i -X OPTIONS -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Hello, World!"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXXX/XXX/XXXX`

Comment: Omit the Content-Type header from your fetch call. The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752537/slack-incoming-webhook-request-header-field-content-type-is-not-allowed-by-acce/45752919#45752919 explains why. Also omit the Access-Control-Allow-\* headers from your fetch call. The Access-Control-Allow-\* headers are response headers, not request headers. The only effect that trying to set them as request headers will have is that it’ll trigger a CORS preflight OPTIONS request. And the as noted in the answer I mentioned, the Slack API doesn’t support receiving OPTIONS requests.

Answer (score 0):

Before POST Request an OPTION request is made. OPTION request receive from server headers:

```
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*"
```

If following request use allowed method, ... is an allowed origin and is an'application/json request, ... everything is all right!

Comment: I'm confused. I know the post isn't happening.

Comment: 'http://localhost:3000' cant make the request to 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXXX/XXX/XXXX'.