# .. from origin .. has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: reactjs, post, cors

I'm fairly new to making API requests. I'm am trying to set up an incoming slack webhook using a simple axios post request from my React project, however I keep receiving the CORS policy error. The request works perfectly in insomnia.

I'm using ngrok to expose my web server running on my local machine to the internet (I assumed this would correct the issue.) So I'm making the request from https://...ngrok.io, however I'm still receiving 'Status Code: 400' in my network tab along with the error above.

```
 axios({
      method: "post",
      url:
        "https://hooks.slack.com/services/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",
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
      data: { text: "Hello, World!" },
    }).then(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  };
```

There are similar errors on stackoverflow, but none fix my error. I'd really like to understand why this is happening so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45752919/2622292

Comment: Nothing changed. I still receive the same error. 

I've tried... headers: { Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*" }
 and no headers, but i receive the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it, for those having the same issue:
What worked for me is setting Content-Type header to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. found it in this thread: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/475 It appears that this triggers "simple request" and therefore avoids triggering CORS preflight. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests